# OO Right Pattern

Tags: .net, oop

Two developers have a dispute on which pattern is the right one. I would be very happy if someone could tell me who is right and why.

Developer 1:

class a has two functions:

```
Remove(int item);
Save();
```

Reasoning:

```
a.Remove(1);
a.Remove(3);
a.Save();
```

This way you can remove items from it's internal list without saving the changes to the database. As soon as you call a.Save() the internal state of the object will be saved to the database.

Developer 2:

class a has only one function

```
Remove(List<int> items);
```

Reasoning:

```
a.Remove(new List<int>{1,2});
```

This way you don't have to remember to save and class a can still only save once.

Are there design patterns or other documents which prove the correct way or is it just style?

Comment: the second case has 2 responsibilities: removing and saving. Therefore, I'd prefer the first case.

Comment: How don't you need to remember to save in the latter example, nothing indicates in your statement that the "Remove" also persists to the database; and this is a matter of preference: I don't see why both methods aren't exposed, for flexibility, but whether the "save" happens as part of "Remove" or explicitly on its own is a design decision specific to your scenario - though the second case hides consequences, which could be undesirable.

Comment: This question should really be on programmers.stackexchange.com or codereview.stackexchange.com. Note that ORMs like EF and NHibernate use pattern #1 for normal operations and a *different* function (or even interface) for batch/direct operations, instead of misusing a function name already used for another purpose

Comment: If you in future would add functions such as Update or Insert or any that perform save to the DB and go with latter approach wouldn't that result in code repetition for Save in each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is very synthetic example, it's hard to tell what's the right way winthout knowing of a real context.

In most real cases first solution is better because of the need for reducing of database requests count and duration.

Take a look at Repository and Unit of Work patterns.

Common activity sequence is:

1. Create Unit of Work.
2. Make some actions with data using Repository (which is mapped to UoW)
3. Make another actions with data using Repository
4. Commit changes through Unit of Work.

Depending on Unit of Work implementation you may

1. Create physical transaction (or connection) at the beginning and push changes immediately. It is flexible equivalent for the second solution.
2. Create physical transaction and commit it at the ending with UoW.Commit
3. Implement different offline locks (pessimistic or optimistic).

So, it's felxible. Single-method solution is less felxible especially if one time you will need to add another action, i.e.

```
Remove(1,2);
Add(5);
```

Talking aboud data access and domain layers, in perspective it may lead to db logic leak and other currently recognized as Anti-patterns (for most cases) things like Active Record.

Comment: "In most real cases first solution is better because of the need for reducing of database requests count and duration." -  right answer, wrong primary reason.

Comment: @MitchWheat, give explanataions. Do you prefer answers containing sophisticated and demagogic reasonings about responsibilities, maintainability, SOLID, etc? I even won't try to talk about general design principles according to this certain case. Some technical stuff (transactions, logging, other "side effects", ...) may by applied transparently to different operations. Thus changing and immediate saving itself is not a problem as soon as it is properly and transaprently implemented (and, of course, required for real practical needs).

Comment: Moreover some frameworks don't require explicit 'save' and push changes on every model change.